# Formula for Temperature Gradient due to Joule Heating

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, electricity, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

I was wondering how to calculate how much the temperature will increase in a cylindrical wire due to current passing through it, I did some googling didn't find anything so I came up with the following and I am posting it here for verification or correction.

Model assumptions:

1- Symmterical cylinder on the z-axis,

2- Uniform current density in $+\hat{k}$ direction,

3- Ignoring thermal radiation.

Key Equations: $$\vec{\dot{q}}=-k\nabla T\quad (1)\\P=I^2R\quad  (2)$$

Steps:

From dimensional analysis of $\vec{\dot{q}}$ we find it is W/m², i.e power over area, which can be encapsulated in the following formula: $P=\oint\vec{\dot{q}}\cdot d\vec{S}$, unpacking that expression for our model exploiting the symmetry and using eq.(2):
$$
I^2R=\dot{q}\oint dS=\dot{q}(2\pi z r_c+\pi r_c^2)=\dot{q}\pi r_c(2z+r_c)\\
\dot{q}=\frac{I^2R}{\pi r_c(2z+r_c)}
$$
With heat flux being in the direction of the current density, substituting in eq.(1) we get:
$$
\frac{I^2R}{\pi r_c(2z+r_c)}=-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\\
T=T_0-\frac{I^2R}{\pi r_c k}\int_0^L{\frac{1}{2z+r_c}dz}\\
T=T_0+\frac{I^2R}{\pi r_c k}\ln{\frac{r_c}{2L+r_c}}\quad (3)
$$

Where eq.(3) should give the -steady-state- temperature for cylindrical conductor. Right?

Glossary: [$\vec{\dot{q}}$ (heat flux density), $k$ (material's thermal conductivity, $T$ (temperature), $P$ (power), $I$ (current), $R$ (wire's resistance), $\vec{S}$ (wire's area vector), $r_c$ (wire's cross-sectional radius), $L$ (wire's length)]

Comment: I realise this formula makes temperature decreases, I thought about reversing the + sign in eq.(3), that seemed to give some reasonable results but I found no errors in the derivation and no reason to do so, so I assume something is faulty in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article gives some useful equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Non-uniform_isotropic_medium) for analyzing heat propagation. Note that it gives also a solution for heat distribution of a cylindrical wire. I think what might be complicating here is choosing the correct boundary conditions: is the wire isolated from the external world? Is it losing the heat at the surface? How much of the heat is being lost?

Another relevant point is using *local* equation for the Joule's heat density, rather than an equation for the total energy generated in the wire:
$$
P = IV = I^2R \longrightarrow q = \mathbf{j}\mathbf{E} = \sigma \mathbf{E}^2,
$$
where $\sigma$ is the conductivity, $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density and $\mathbf{E}$ is the local electric field.
Thus, you need to know not only the distribution of the currentd ensity in the cross-section, but how the electric field changes along the wire.

At first this may seem as complicating your life, but I hope it will lead you to think through your approximations and come up with a simple practical solution.