# Is there a relationship between the electrical power supplied to a material and the emitted wavelength?

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation

I have a graphite bar that is used in a vacuum furnace that serves as a heating resistor and the heat is provided by radiation, so I would like to know by knowing the electrical input power (240kW), the radiative power emitted, to then know the final temperature of my load (parts), this part I know how to do it. Just the part I mentioned at the beginning I can't find any relation to it.
I started with an idea that I considered the bar as a black body, so theoretically my bar is at 1400 K for 240kW of electrical power (this is consistent with the maximum oven temperature set by the oven manufacturer)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/649050/formula-for-temperature-gradient-due-to-joule-heating) may help you also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To know the temperature of the object when dissipating a given power, you must know its size and shape and how it contracts other materials, not just its material. And then typically you must do a FEM analysis rather than expect a simple algebraic solution.

Comment: Which software should I use for this application, I use some of them on mechanical analysis, but for the application in my problem I don't know of any. Could you recommend me something ?

Answer (score 2):

The material is not emitting a single wave length, but rather a continuous spectrum, which is described by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law):
[image]

The temperature then describes the shape of the curve and the [position of the peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Peaks). One could the determine the position of the peak wave length in terms of temperature - see also [*Wien law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law).

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify but I was only looking for the strongest wavelength, but yes there is a whole spectrum, but it doesn't depend on the material so?

Comment: How do you determine the temperature - by the shape of the spectrum? So you know the maxmimum wave-length (or, if you don't, see the derivations regarding the Peak of Planck's curve and Wien law, linked in the answer.)

Comment: Where material enters the picture is when the electric current is transformed into heat, accordng to Jule's law: $P=I^2R$.

Comment: Actually, I did not determine the temperature, it was provided to me. However, if you have an idea of how to find it, I'm interested. I assume it was determined by the shape of the spectrum, I don't know if we can get any direct formula for that.

Comment: [Stephan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) probably

Comment: The material does, or at least can, affect the spectrum because real objects aren't perfect blackbodies. Certainly if the object is a sodium gas cell, for example, it's radiation spectrum can be very different from the blackbody spectrum.

Comment: @ThePhoton this is true. However, the OP explicitly states that they consider the object as a black body, which is characterized by certain temperature.

Comment: They say they started with that idea, not that they are confident that it is correct. Admittedly for a carbon rod, it's probably reasonable, but I read the question as asking for a general solution, not a solution that only applies to carbon rods.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think the question is not very precise (or too broad) in this respect. It is an interesting direction to explore - would you like to write an answer discussing this in more details?